# How to add "everyone" to the share point security group programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How to add "everyone" to the share point security group programmatically?

using UI I can add everyone, how I can do the same using code?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `c:0(.s|true` to add `Everyone` to the group.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite"))
{
    SPWeb root = site.RootWeb;
    SPGroup group = root.Groups["GroupName"];
    SPUser user = root.EnsureUser("c:0(.s|true");
    group.AddUser(user);
    group.Update();
}
```